# Why there is a missing one 'new line' in a django template after 'POST' or 'GET' request?

Tags: html, textarea, html-parsing

After form validation my textarea loses its first line.

The result page where textarea is displayed corresponds to the same view and the template as a page where user enters data. In other words the pages are same.

In my code I have something like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    f = MyForm( request.POST )
    if f.is_valid(): # f is a form
        context.update( value = f.cleaned_data[ 'value' ] )
        # then 'value' becomes a 'value' context variable for a template.
```

The fragment from a template:

```
...
<textarea name='value'>{{value}}</textarea> 
<!-- It's a template for a result page -->
...
```

It's interesting that if the textarea has many '\n' lines at the beginning then for each  'POST' request it loses one of them (and **only** one of them) in a result page where posted data is displayed in the textarea.

Can anyone help? How to come around the problem without a hack in the code?

I would like textarea displays all beginning '\n' lines which a user enters on a previous page.

**More**.

The data comes from a client normally - if we output 'value' in a view then none newlines are missing. The problem is for further displaying in a template.

Environment: Windows, Firefox/Opera.

Comment: Have you looked at the rendered HTML? Are there any clues there that may indicate how the value is being rendered?

Comment: does this happen even if the first line is not a newline?

Comment: @cdhowie If I assign '\n\r\n\r' to a view context variable in my view then I have 2 new lines. If I set '\n\n' then a have only one. Is this a clue?

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo No.

Comment: @sergzach Could be. Every browser I know of uses `\r\n` (not `\n\r`, by the way) as the newline separator when posting data.

Comment: @cdhowie Sorry. In case of '\r\n' we have the same problem - only one line displays (for '\r\n\r\ntest' ).

Comment: @sergzach Probably because `\n\r\n\r` was being treated as three newlines: `\n`, `\r\n`, and `\r`. One of them was probably being lopped off somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is Django-specific?

```
<html>
<body>
<textarea>`[CR]LF`
`[CR]LF`
test</textarea>    
</body>
</html>
```

Has only one newline in my browser when saved as a normal .html file. The browser takes the first newline as just "HTML code formatting", and not part of the value.

**EDIT**

You should be able to solve this by modifiying your template like this:

```
<textarea name='value'>
{{value}}</textarea> 
<!-- It's a template for a result page -->
```

Only newlines after the first are displayed in the box (i.e. if you have 3, you get 2, if you have 2 you get 1, if you have 1 you get 0, if you have 0 you get 0 again). This is because the first newline is consumed as part of the tag by your browser, so changing the template to already include this first newline should solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure that is Django-specific. It's only strange that I post one textarea content and get another content after a request.

Comment: The content is the same; your web browser interprets it differently. I made the above example by direct substitution with the value you were expecting.

Comment: Your answer - are you sure? But what if the value has not leading \n? In this case we have a newline at the beginning despite the fact of the absence.

Comment: OK, I will check your answer later and will report a result.

Comment: @sergzach no, you won't, the browser takes the first newline after the `textarea` as part of the tag and not part of the text. Just try it out in a simple HTML file - "<textarea>`NEWLINE`test</textarea>" doesn't display a newline. Only newlines after the first are displayed in the box (i.e. if you have 3, you get 2, if you have 2 you get 1, if you have 1 you get 0).

Answer (score 0):

I thought browsers ignore /n as a new line rendering text in html? html uses

```
<br>
```

for a new line. To render a block of text you can include it in your form as a list, where each line of data is a new list item, then render it in your template using:

```
{{ text_list|join:"<br>"}}
```

/n will be preserved in your text so you can still use it for regex etc...

Comment: This is a textarea, it works with pre-formatted text. `<br/>` is outputted literally.

Comment: Yeah, me too - about `join` in template tags :) It's difficult to visit SO and not learn something new :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below codes, I faced a similar issues, this is how i resolved it.

```
<pre>{{text_list|safeseq|join:"\r\n"}}</pre> 
<p>{{text_list|safeseq|join:"\n"}}</p>
<p><pre>{{text_list|safeseq|join:"\r\n"}}</p>
```

LMK